# awk Decimal & whole number check check in single regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

I have a `|` delimited file

at 5th column it contains values like

```
10
1
10.01
100.02
500
6
```

so in AWK I do

```
awk -F '|' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ || $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ || $1 ~ /^[0-9]$/' file
```

My question is how can I club this three checks in single regex in awk as I have other validations in awk as well

Comment: `|| $5 ~ /^[0-9]$` is useless.

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -nE '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,1}$/p' file`

Comment: @Cyrus thanks for sed option ,awk is important as I check length of other fields & NF values as well

Comment: Why are you doing this? A regexp isn't the way to check if a value is a number - just do `$5 == ($5+0)`. Also, your sample input doesn't have 5 fields so why bother telling us it's the 5th field when that is completely irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton your way is brilliant for Numeric check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Cyrus comment

```
awk -F '|' '$1 ~ '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,1}$/' filename
```

seems to be working

Thanks to ED comment, even below way works for numeric check

```
awk -F '|' '$1 == ($1+0)'
```

Comment: `{0,1}` is conveniently written simply `?`

Comment: No, the regex in this answer permits one or more (`+`) digits after the decimal point. Exactly two digits would be `[0-9]{2}`.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed `+`